# Finding maximum value using R method

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $5 \sin x - 12 \cos x = R \sin (x- \alpha ) $ where R>0 and $\alpha$ is acute . Find the maximum value of $5 \sin x - 12 \cos x + 1 $

My R value is = $13$ and $\alpha = 67.4 $

For maximum value , what I'm taught is $R= \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} $ will give u the maximum or minimum / maximum value of R .

However , when I went to Internet , they told me that for maximum value = R, $sin (x - \alpha) = 1$

What does that mean ? And subsequently , back to the question, why is the maximum value 14 but not 13 ?

Comment: what states the $R$ method?

Comment: What value do you get for  $5 \sin x - 12 \cos x + 1$ when $x=157.4^\circ$, i.e $90^\circ+67.4^\circ$?

Comment: I don't get it. The function $5 \sin x - 12 \cos x + 1$ has no maximum inside the interval $(0,\pi/2)$. It is $14$ but when $$x=\pi -\arctan\left(\frac{5}{12}\right)\approx 157° 38'$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you have to find the maximum value of $5\sin x -12\cos x +1$. Thus, $$\max(5\sin x -12\cos x +1) = \max(5\sin x -12\cos x) + 1 = 13+ 1 = 14$$

Comment: What if now, I want to find the corresponding values of $x$ for the maximum value. Why is $\sin (x+67.4)= 14$ wrong to find the maximum x value ? But $\sin (x+67.4)= 1$ correct ?

Comment: @user175089 Note that the constant $1$ does not affect the answer in any way. It is independent of $x$, so it remains same as before.

Answer (score 1):

$R\sin(x-\alpha) =$

$R\sin(x)\cos(\alpha)- R\cos(x)sin(\alpha);$

Comparing:

$R \cos(\alpha) = 5;$

$R\sin(\alpha) =12.$

$R^2 = 12^2 + 5^2,$ hence

$R = 13$ ( positive R).

The angle: $\tan(\alpha) =12/5$, $\alpha$  acute.

$\max( 13\sin(x-\alpha) )=13×1$.

(Maximum of the expression) $+1$ is $14$ .